# Right Click brings firefox menu instead of executing jquery code

Tags: jquery, datatable

My issue : if i right click on a TD inside a Datatable, the following code is successfully executed :

```
$('#mytable tbody tr td').mousedown(function(event){
if(event.which == 3)  //1 for mouseleft button, 2 for middle, 3 for right
{   console.log("Hello");}
});
```

But, it works only one time !, then, each time i perform a right click again, i get a contextual Firefox menu, instead of my Jquery code.

I tried to add event.preventDefault(); event.stopPropagation(); but it doesn't work. Maybe i put it in the wrong place.

```
oTable = $('#mytable').DataTable({
fnDrawCallback: function () {
event.stopPropagation();
event.stopImmediatePropagation();
};
```

Any idea ?

Comment: try using `on()` method... change `$('#mytable tbody tr td').mousedown(function(event){` to `$(document).on('mousedown','#mytable tbody tr td', function(event){`

Comment: or better to use `$(document).on('contextmenu', '#mytable tbody tr td', function(event){`

Comment: kindly check https://jsfiddle.net/RRR0308/7hq1o31v/

Comment: Thank you RRR, it works fine

Comment: You should click on the "Post your answer" button, if you want i give you some points

Comment: Sure will post it as an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi kindly check https://jsfiddle.net/RRR0308/7hq1o31v/ use `return false` instead of `stopPropogation()`

**Demo Code:**

**HTML**

```
<div class="div1">

</div>

<div class="msg">

</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.div1{
  height:200px;
  width:200px;
  background:blue;
  margin:50px;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var i=1;
  $(document).on('contextmenu', '.div1', function(e){

    $('.msg').text('right clicked '+i+' times');
    i++;
    return false;
  });
});
```